# Handling hardware dependency while unit testing

Tags: design, unit-testing, c, tdd, mocking

I am writing a driver for an IMU sensor using test driven development approach. Communication protocol of choice is SPI. Using CubeMX and STM32F415 processor, SPI interface is implemented in *stm32f4xx_hal_spi.h* file, which contains many and more function declarations. Note this SPI interface is processor-specific and IMU driver may also be implemented on different platforms so flexibility is also important.

For test driven development needs I have to mock SPI functions I use within driver code. I came up with two possible options:

**1)** Original SPI header file *stm32fxx_hal_spi.h* is included directly into driver header. Its entire contents gets mocked, even though only very few functions are acutally used in sensor driver.

**PRO**

- straightforward implementation

**CON**

- actual SPI driver files have to be copied into sensor driver project
- mocking fat interface

**2)** Within driver project create *spi.h* header. Re-declare functions that are used by driver but are originally already declared in *stm32fxx_hal_spi.h* . Mocking *spi.h* gives mocks only for functions actually used. 
 
**PRO**

- no need to copy processor-specific SPI driver files into sensor driver project
- mock only things used

**CON**

- test driving seems straightforward but am unsure how to integrate with hardware and *stm32fxx_hal_spi.h* file

It seems to me that second approach does a better job in terms of abstracting spi implementation into a single header file. But as mentioned, I am unsure how to proceed to link this to actual spi driver files during integration of sensor driver into entire project.

Is any of these considered a valid approach? Is there a generally accepted approach for this during driver development?

Comment: Have you read [TDD for Embedded C by James Grenning](https://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c)?

Comment: Yes I have, and it's an excellent book! However, I have not found an answer to this particular question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using a conventional object oriented approach. Even with plain C code, this is fairly easy.

```
struct spiInterace {
   void* privateData;
   void (*eachFunctionInSPIInterface)();
};
typedef struct spiInterace  spiInterace ;
```

Then your real SPI interface provides a 'new function':

```
spiInterace* mkstm32f4xx_hal_spi()
{
   // malloc object, add any needed private data pointer (like
   // to memory mapped or open file descriptor) and fill in
   // function pointers to APIs now moved to static functions
}
```

... Similarly for your 'mock' SPI device driver.

Change all your calls to indirect through the spiIntrface object:

```
   spiInterface* spiI = // call one mkFunction or the other for testing or real;
   // instead of earlier call to eachFunctionInSPIInterface(someSPIdesignator);
   spiI->eachFunctionInSPIInterface ();
```

Then testing is easy - just construct one or the other spiInterface.

Hope that helps!